# Spring Mvc with async support vs Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

As i know(add if i miss smth) when we use `Spring MVC` application we have a pool of threads from our server(Tomcat...) when request is coming one of our thread from pool handle this request, sometimes it's a bad because if task take a long time our thread will be busy all this time, to avoid this behavoir we can change return type of our controller from for Example String to `Callable<String>` or `DefferedResult<String>`, and now worker thread from tomcat give execution to thread from ExecutorService( that we configure in `@Configuration` class), its better because tomcat thread can handle others request and will not waiting for execution of each of them.
But i don't understand the WebFlux idea. As i understand from official doc , we have single thread that handle all requests and then (I don't understand how) return responses, but what if one request wait for long task (Query to data base) does it mean that this thread will wait until current task completion or it will create new thread for this task,if so how it's differente from Callable and DefferedResult?

Thank in advance

Comment: As I know, this is a long and rambling question, I didn't make it to the end - but perhaps someone may. If they do, I hope that they are able to help you understand in a way that the official documentation could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video:

https://www.infoq.com/presentations/servlet-reactive-stack

explains how requests are handled in servlet and reactive stacks and the benefits of the reactive approach.

There is also  good explanation why **RxJava** (another reactive library) are better than **Futures**:

http://reactivex.io/intro.html

> Techniques like Java Futures are straightforward to use for a single
>   level of asynchronous execution but they start to add non-trivial
>   complexity when they’re nested.
>
> It is difficult to use Futures to optimally compose conditional
>   asynchronous execution flows (or impossible, since latencies of each
>   request vary at runtime). This can be done, of course, but it quickly
>   becomes complicated (and thus error-prone) or it prematurely blocks on
>   Future.get(), which eliminates the benefit of asynchronous execution.
>
> ReactiveX Observables, on the other hand, are intended for composing
>   flows and sequences of asynchronous data.